# How to stop Keyup event from triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Console.log is printed twice. I have tried using e.stopPropagation(),e.preventDefault() and .stop(). It does not work.
The console.log should trigger only once

```
$('html').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        console.log("delete press");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: "_console.log will be only trigger once_" Then how do you know the event is triggered twice? Also, stopping event propagation on HTML element does nothing, an event can't bubble out of the document anyway.

Comment: Not enough information. Posted code can't behave like you described.

Comment: Can you try .unbind and then .bind. It could be that the event has been bound twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back. I ended up using `$.unbind()` and `$.bind()`. I would first call `$.unbind()` to remove any callback functions to the event that were potentially already bound to event. Then, I would call `$.bind()` on the event so it can do what I want it to do.

```
$('html').unbind('keyup');
$('html').bind('keyup', function (e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to debounce the event.

You can use something like `lodash` to do this easily, or you can roll your own if you want to learn how it works.

```
function handler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        console.log("delete press");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
$('html').keyup(lodash.debounce(handler, 250));
```

250 here is the number of milliseconds to debounce an event, also notice how the event is wrapped.

The documentation for all the options can be found here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce

Comment: The provided code by OP won't fire twice, something else is missing.

Comment: The problem here is, that the question doesn't represent any reproducable problem, please don't make speculations in answers.

Comment: @Teemu a hardware triggered event is firing twice needing a debounce isn't a speculation, it is a common problem.

Comment: @Durga His english needs a bit of help if you read the question he says the console log fires twice and the last line he means he wants it to only fire once.

Comment: Then most likely the actual hardware issue is a heavy finger on the keyboard, or a dirty keyboard (__keyup event is not repeated__), those are something you can't programmatically fix. You might be correct with the translation of the last sentence, though.

Answer (score 0):

Detaching the event with `off()` also works

```
 $('html').off('keyup').on('keyup',function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 46) {
    console.log("delete press");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

OR

execute the event handler only once using `one()` as

```
$('html').one('keyup',function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 46) {
    console.log("delete press");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

});